# Dynamic prop component not working in Vue 3

Tags: vue.js, dynamic, components, updates, vue-props

There's a component with a prop, a src from an image. I can't figure out how to pass from other component.

The component with prop:

```
<template>
<img :src="avatar" />
</template>

<script>
    export default {        
        props: ['avatar']
    }
</script>
```

Other component:

```
<Card avatar="avatar" />

<script>
export default {        
        components: {
            Card
        },
        data() {
            return {
                avatar: ''
            }
        },
        // fetch updates avatar ...
</script>
```

I tested, avatar is being updated in the component, but the props on other component, not. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing in a string "avatar" with `avatar="avatar"`, you probably want to do `:avatar="avatar"` (with a leading `:`) to pass in the variable